# Sound Driver is messed up, and mic doesn't work correctly under ubuntu 12

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, sound, alsa, microphone

### Quick

Ubuntu 12.04 sound pops on boot and shutdown, and MIC picks up non-existent static. Edit: please note, Audio out is fine.

### Issue

On shut-down and boot I often hear a loud blast from the speakers under 12.04. I was able to get the microphone to work by using the help from "[Lenovo Ideapad built-in mic not working in 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/199258/lenovo-ideapad-built-in-mic-not-working-in-12-04)", and running:

```
sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

and then adding

```
alias snd-card-0 snd-hda-intel
options snd-hda-intel model=auto
```

followed by rebooting.

This made the microphone able to record, However, there is still a VERY loud background noise/fuzz/static that is recorded by the microphone. This issue is confirmed to not be present under Windows 8 on the same machine (I'm not sure about ubuntu13)

These outputs may have been affected by the fact that I modified `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`, I don't know.

```
$ cat /proc/asound/cards
0 [MID            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel MID
                     HDA Intel MID at 0xc2610000 irq 49
1 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                     HDA Intel PCH at 0xc2614000 irq 50`
```

and

```
$ lspci | grep -i audio

00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)`
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)`
```

### Probably unrelated background hardware driver info:

I have a Lenovo y410p laptop running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I have fixed most of the graphics issues (I get graphical out finally! but I still have to manually change the brightness every boot.), most of the BIOS/UEFI issues, and it triple boots 13.10 and win8. It is up-to-date, and runs the community supported version of Bumblebee to deal with nVidia's lack of direct support for nVidia Optimus products (a reason I might move from CUDA to OpenCL). Not related, but sometimes after the computer has gone to sleep/screen shuts off, and wakes up, the mouse will ONLY move if the left mouse button is pressed -which is a pain (because I can't properly click anything - to save what I'm doing) but fixes itself by logging out and logging back in...

edit: I figure I should put the kernel version and stuff too:

```
$ uname -a
Linux myLenovoLaptop 3.8.0-34-generic #49~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Nov 13 18:05:00 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.8.0-34-generic (buildd@toyol) (gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) ) #49~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Nov 13 18:05:00 UTC 2013

$ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
bbswitch               13611  0 
dm_crypt               23051  1 
pci_stub               12622  1 
vboxpci                23236  0 
vboxnetadp             13382  0 
vboxnetflt             23478  0 
vboxdrv               283008  4 vboxpci,vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt
bnep                   18258  2 
rfcomm                 47864  12 
parport_pc             28284  0 
ppdev                  17113  0 
binfmt_misc            17540  1 
nls_iso8859_1          12713  1 
arc4                   12573  2 
snd_hda_codec_realtek    79962  1 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     37463  1 
iwldvm                249093  0 
snd_hda_intel          44339  7 
snd_hda_codec         141761  3 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel
uvcvideo               82214  0 
snd_hwdep              13668  1 snd_hda_codec
coretemp               13596  0 
videobuf2_core         40785  1 uvcvideo
videodev              130053  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core
snd_pcm               102477  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
mac80211              630977  1 iwldvm
videobuf2_vmalloc      13056  1 uvcvideo
joydev                 17613  0 
snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
videobuf2_memops       13202  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
snd_rawmidi            30417  1 snd_seq_midi
btusb                  22431  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
bluetooth             247165  24 bnep,rfcomm,btusb
kvm_intel             137899  0 
kvm                   455932  1 kvm_intel
snd_seq                61930  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_timer              29989  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
iwlwifi               183603  1 iwldvm
snd_seq_device         14497  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
alx                    73230  0 
psmouse                97873  0 
cfg80211              525326  3 iwldvm,mac80211,iwlwifi
mei                    41820  0 
mac_hid                13253  0 
snd                    69533  23 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
soundcore              12680  1 snd
snd_page_alloc         18798  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
mdio                   13807  1 alx
wmi                    19256  0 
lpc_ich                17144  0 
serio_raw              13215  0 
microcode              23017  0 
ideapad_laptop         18596  0 
sparse_keymap          13890  1 ideapad_laptop
lp                     17799  0 
parport                46562  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp
ghash_clmulni_intel    13259  0 
aesni_intel            55495  1391 
ablk_helper            13597  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 20501  4 ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel,ablk_helper
lrw                    13294  1 aesni_intel
aes_x86_64             17255  1 aesni_intel
xts                    12922  1 aesni_intel
gf128mul               14951  2 lrw,xts
ahci                   25879  4 
i915                  620571  4 
libahci                31606  1 ahci
drm_kms_helper         49597  1 i915
drm                   287564  5 i915,drm_kms_helper
i2c_algo_bit           13564  1 i915
video                  19652  1 i915
```

### Update

Created 2 new OS partitions for upgrading. Upgraded Linux side from Ubuntu 12 to 14. Upgraded Windows side from 8 to 8.1. Old OS's remain.
Still does not work on Ubuntu14.04. Sound is fine in win8.1

Comment: I'm using 14.04 and I have same problem. Constant mic static.

Comment: @XiaoChuanYu : Confirmed as still an issue for me after upgrade to 14.04.01. Issue still unresolved.