# Internal mic of Lenovo Ideapad s210 not working

Tags: lenovo, alsa, microphone

I recently bought a lenovo ideapad s210 and installed Ubuntu 13.10 on it.

Overall it works pretty good, but I can't figure out how to get the internal microphone to work.

I've tried adding in lines to the `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` file as has been suggested in this thread [Lenovo Ideapad built-in mic not working in 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/199258/lenovo-ideapad-built-in-mic-not-working-in-12-04).

But still no luck.

How to fix this?

Comment: This helped me: https://gist.github.com/Therises/d2e91c81af1574f9069635d520fdc7ec

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem.

I can get the mic to work in audacity if I select hw:0,0 as mic input.

But, I cannot get it to stay as default.

It seems the problem comes down to both mic inputs (internal mic & headset input on side) being detected, but only one being able to be seen by gnome.

I could not get it set permanently, no matter what I tried. I tried using pacmd, but to no avail.

I have seen it working in Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS, when a colleague installed it on the S210. And in that case 2 mics were listed in the sound setting.

If you plug in a headset with a mic, you'll see that it works, cause that's what it's set to.

Oddly, if I launch pavucontrol, and set it to microphone, it will work while it is open. But it won't stick.